# how to fetch the value from sqlite database and display on new table layout in android

Tags: android, sqlite

in my application,there are three screen..in first window(MainActivity) one button is here..when i click the button new window is open,there is edittext for user value..and also refresh button on second scrren ..
after entering value into edittext and refresh button the value are stored into database.my problem is that how to fetch them and display on new table layout in new window..

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrcMy.png)
  [second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSXvk.png)

Comment: What u tried? post it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use button or any event to fetch the value from the database. you can run query on the database and store the value in the cursor. as far as code is concerned for fetching the value from the database you may http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html or http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/